# How can i count the number of processed strings in Smalltalk?

Tags: string, count, smalltalk

My program counts the number of the processed strings's letters. I would also like to count the number of string but i have no idea how to, i havent found any useful stuff in google. Thanks for your patience.

```
|s b|
b := Bag new.

[s := stdin nextLine. s ~= 'exit'] whileTrue: [
    s do: [:c |
        b add: c.
    ].
].

b displayNl.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: Sorry my bad.
for example:
apple vodka beer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as I can tell you want to count the number of occurrences of letters in a collection of strings. First, of all, I'd suggest you not to do that while the client is typing (unless you really need to react immediately).

Now imagine that you gathered all the input into a variable called `input`. To get the occurrences, you can just do `input asBag`, and this will convert the string (collection of characters into a bag). So now you have your first task done. Then it depends on what in your opinion is a word. For example, you can use `input substrings` to break your big string into small ones using whitespace (tab, space, newline, etc…) as a separator. Otherwise, you can use `input substrings: ','` where you specify which separator do you want to use (in the example it is a comma). Now to count the occurrences of the words in your string you can use `input substrings asBag`.

Of course, if you want to do it as a user enters the data you can do something like this:

```
|line characters words|
characters := Bag new.
words := Bag new.

[ line := stdin nextLine. line ~= 'exit'] whileTrue: [
   characters addAll: line.
   words addAll: line substrings
].

characters displayNl.
words displayNl
```

Comment: I would add that `characters addAll: line` is what replaces `s do: [:c | b add: c]`, `s` playing the same role as `line`. Both are equivalent but the first one is terser.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to count the number of lines read from stdin, you could do it like in any imperative language: Use a counter.

```
| numberOfLines s |
numberOfLines := 0.
[s := stdin nextLine. s ~= 'exit'] whileTrue: [
    numberOfLines := numberOfLines + 1.
    "..."].
numberOfLines displayNl.
```

Or, following Uko's answer, collect all the lines into another collection and use its size afterwards:

```
| lines s |
lines := OrderedCollection new.
[s := stdin nextLine. s ~= 'exit'] whileTrue: [lines add: s. "..."].
lines size displayNl.
```